# Scala RegexParser for method call parsing

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I am trying to write a Parser that parses methods given in a string format. For example, I have 2 method calls named `(naiveMethod.contains(naiveObj))` and `(naiveMethod.get())`

I have written the following code to try and parse this:

```
def string: Parser[Any] = """[a-zA-Z\_]+""".r ^^ {_.toString}

def obj: Parser[Any] = """[a-zA-Z\_]+""".r ^^ {_.toString} | "(" ~> functionCall <~ ")"

def methodCall: Parser[String] = string ~ "(" ~ ((string ~ ")") | ")") ^^ {
 case str1 ~ "(" ~ str2 ~ ")" =>
   val stringBuilder = str1 + "(" + str2 + ")"
   stringBuilder
 case str1 ~ "(" ~ ")" =>
  val stringBuilder = obj1 + "()"
  stringBuilder
}

def functionCall: Parser[Any] =
  obj ~ rep("." ~ methodCall)  ^^{
  case obj ~ list => list.foldLeft(obj) {
   case (obj1, "." ~ methodCall) =>
   println(obj1 +  methodCall.toString)
 }
}
```

Problem I'm having is that even though `string` call in the `methodCall` function gives me the appropriate `string` names, they  **don't**  match any of the cases mentioned in `methodCall`. I'm not sure where exactly I'm going wrong, so any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `string ~ "(" ~ ((string ~ ")") | ")")` has type `Parser[Any ~ String ~ Serializable]`.

By default the match `case str1 ~ "(" ~ str2 ~ ")"` is parsed like `case ((str1 ~ "(") ~ str2) ~ ")"`. So Scala tries to match the `Serializable` with `")"`, the  `String` with `str2`, and `Any` with `str1 ~ "("`. This is wrong and the match fails.

To make Scala match in the desired order, you can wrap the `str2 ~ ")"` part, that should match that `Serializable` in brackets. The following code works:

```
def methodCall: Parser[String] = string ~ "(" ~ ((string ~ ")") | ")") ^^ {
  case str1 ~ "(" ~ (str2 ~ ")") =>
    val stringBuilder = str1 + "(" + str2 + ")"
    stringBuilder
  case str1 ~ "(" ~ ")" =>
    val stringBuilder = str1 + "()"
    stringBuilder
}
```